# Header Fixed CSS - Transform Translate X

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer com que o `header` do site em mobile fique `fixed` na tela.

Porém, tenho um botão nesse `header` que abre o MENU a direita do site, usando o `transform: translateX(-15%)` aplicado no `main`. Quando estou no topo do site funciona perfeitamente.

Agora se o site não estiver no topo, estiver no meio da tela por exemplo, ao clicar no botão, o MENU é mostrado, mas o `header` some. E eu descobri que é por causa do `transform: translate` no `main`.

Isso é um **BUG** ?

Tem um *hack* para resolver isso ?

### CSS

```
main#main{
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: #FFF;
    &.is-active{
        transform: translateX(-210px);
    }
}

header#header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a7ddb3;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #01613c;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

### JS

```
var clickDeviceEvent    = 'touchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
var menuMobile          = $("main, .menu-language, body, .open-menu");
urlBase                 = $('body').data('base');

// Abrir Menu Mobile
$('.open-menu').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    menuMobile.toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema bem parecido a algum tempo atras..
Primeiramente verifique se estão definidos o posicionamento vertical e horizontal do header (top ou bottom, left ou right). Esse é o principal motivo para bugs de elementos com "fixed" no meio da pagina.

Caso isso não resolva, poderia me informar qual o navegador que está utilizando e sistema operacional do dispositivo? se possível envie também a URL do site para facilitar.

Comment: Está no localhost. O `header` tem as propriedades `top` e `left` definidas. 0 e 0 respectivamente. Estou usando o simulador do Chrome. Não tenho dispositivo em mãos.

Comment: Compreendo.
Eu desconheço qualquer bug relacionado ao translate, porem no can i use  esta descrita a seguinte Known issues: 

"Transforms may break position:fixed styles of contained elements" você pode ver aqui -> http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

acho que pode estar relacionado a isso. Tenta posicionar com absolute, apenas para teste.

Você poderia me mandar o trecho de CSS do elemento header?

Comment: Adicionei a minha pergunta.

Comment: Ótimo,
Coloque o elemento header, diretamente no body, ou seja, deixe o body como nodeParent do header. Modifique o position de "fixed" para "absolute" no header e me diga se houve mudança.

Comment: Coloquei o `header` como children do `body` e alterei para `position: absolute`. O `header` ficou no `top: 0` quando rolei a página. Não é o que eu preciso, preciso que o `header` acompanhe a rolagem... ou isso era algum **debug** ?

Comment: isso, era apenas um debug devido a Known issues que te citei acima do Can i use. "Elementos container com position:fixed associados ao transform em geral podem ter bugs".
Outro debug que você pode executar é adicionar um container com o postion:fixed e o header dentro com position:relative ou initial.
ex: <div style="position:fixed"><header style="position:relative"></header></div>

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27463/discussion-between-rafael-kendrik-and-diego-souza).

Comment: Eu já tinha lido aquela pergunta e testei as respostas que você me mandou no chat. Nenhum deu certo. Estranho isso.

Comment: Acredito que seja um bug de navegador, conforme foi descrito pela can i use -> http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d Known issues 3 e nesse topico aberto aqui na Stackoverflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform.

Acredito que o melhor seria tentar uma solução alternativa!
De qualquer forma, continuarei buscando uma solução, e caso descubra volto aqui apresentar ela pra você. Boa sorte!